# How far east of flagstaff?

Tags: trigonometry

I am stucked in a problem of application of trigonometry.

The question states:A motor home travels at $50 mph$ for 6 hours in a direction of $115^{\circ}$ from flagstaff,Arizona.At the end of that time,how far east of flagstaff is the motor home?

I am not getting what the author mean from how far east of flagstaff.Using relation between speed and time,I can obtain the distance travelled in the direction of $115^{\circ}$.But what I am actually asked to compute?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There are two keys to the problem: [1] $115^{\circ}$ is somewhat ambiguous and may represent $25^{\circ}$ to the east of due north, or it may represent $25^{\circ}$ to the southeast of due east.  The two interpretations give different answers.  [2] Depending on which interpretation you choose, the easterly direction will either be $r\cos(65^\circ)$ or $r\cos(25^\circ)$, where $r$ is the total distance traveled, re $50$ mph $\times 6$ hours.

Comment: @user2661923  Many problem-posers are disturbingly sloppy in specifying directions for trig problems.  Given that the problem asks "how far _east_..." leads me to believe that "navigational bearing" is being used:  $ \ 115 \ $ in that case means $ \ 115º \ $ _clockwise_ from due North.  So your second suggestion is likely what is intended.  (My feeling on this is that if this were an exam problem worded thus, the instructor _must_ accept  students' (correctly calculated) answers based on that interpretation, regardless of what the instructor may have intended.)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a circle and an arrow, the radius of that circle would be 50mph * 6h = 300 miles, however that is not taking into the account what direction did you travel, if you drive either north, south or west then you travel 300 miles but you traveled 0 miles towards the east.

The arrow would be the direction you traveled, you can calculate how far to the left(west) of right (east) you traveled multiplying the magnitude of the vector (300 miles) by the cosine of the angle (115°), in a similar way you can calculate how far up(north) or down(south) you traveled multiplying the magnitude by the sine of the angle.

[image]

Comment: See my comment, following the question.  I regard the wording of the question as ambiguous.

Comment: @user2661923 Indeed, the wording is ambiguous.